# Automatically add a link to the top after printing a paged data frame in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want my documents to knit such that whenever I print
a paged dataframe in R markdown that the following lines are printed below it:

```
<a href='#top' style='float: right;'>Back to top</a>
```

so the user can jump back to the top where the TOC is.

For example, if the following R chunk was knit with df_print set to `paged` in the yaml header, I am expecting the output to automatically have a "Back to top" link below it.

```
mtcars
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `toc_float: true` to the YAML header may suffice.

The contents would then float along, and save having a link at every data frame.

```
title: "My notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged    
    toc: true
    toc_float: true
```